# How do you know if your Autoencoder network is fully connected?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I am new in deep learning and I am confused about fully connected network. Is an Autoencoder with more than one hidden layers a type of deep neural network (DNN)? Is DNN always fully connected? Let's say an Autoencoder network with three hidden layers was built using H2O R package, how do you know if the Autoencoder network that you build is fully connected?

Answer (score 2):

> Is Autoencoder with more than one hidden layers a type of deep neural
>   network (DNN)?

Yes.

> Is DNN always fully connected?

No. For example [Echo State Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_state_network) are sparsely connected DNNs.

> how do you know if the Autoencoder network that you build is fully
>   connected?

I am not sure about R because I don't use it but for Keras/Python you can read the [layer descriptions](https://keras.io/). The most common predefined layers (Dense, Convolutional, RNN, LSTM..) are fully connected. If you want to have a sparsely connected layer, then you can probably create a custom one using a [Lambda Layer](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda).

Comment: Some people refer to fully-connected layers meaning `Dense` layers, which would not include convolutional or recurrent layers.